# Resource dictionary Localization

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which contains resource dictionary.

I wish to generate fr-FR resource from existing en-US resource.
So I used LocBaml.exe, but instead of getting text in resource file, the out put CSV file contains information from resource file and application parameters (like height, width, margin etc.)

I tried using:

```
LocBaml.exe /parse WPF_App.resources.dll /out:test.csv
```

Anyone have an idea that how can I generate CSV file which contain only text from resource file?

Comment: Why not load the dictionary as an xml file, and get everything you want with and XML reader?

Comment: Here my aim is to generate dll for fr-FR language. So in my application i used resource dictionary to hold localization for en-US.
Is their any other way to do the same, i don't need resx file implementation.